# 'goo' was not declared in this scope, c++

Tags: c++, g++

i got a problem. I got 3 files, foo.h, foo.cpp and main.cpp.

foo.h looks like:

```
void goo();
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

void goo()
{
    (something)
}
```

and main.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    goo();
    return 0;
}
```

This generates error 'goo' was not declared in this scope, but I can't find any clue why is this happening. Is this linker error?

Comment: In foo.h, replace `goo();` with `void goo();`. If you don't supply a return type, it's `int` by default.

Comment: @djikay Not in C++. In this case it's just (another) call to `goo()` after preprocessing.

Comment: @Praetorian: Indeed, you are correct. g++ will complain but can be forced to allow it: *warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'goo' with no type [-fpermissive]*

Comment: I have two suggestions. The first is get a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and the second is **read** it.

Comment: when you compile are you writing `g++ main.cpp foo.cpp -o prog`, if not then yes it is a linker error

Comment: "not declared in this scope" is clearly not a linker error.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths that's right, i'm wrong, linker error would say `undefined reference to 'goo()' `, my bad

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake. I corrected it.
@James I did it as you said. Still same error. It's like it does not include foo.h.

Comment: @Gogetek Your current code example (assuming you comment out `(something)`) compiles for me in g++ on windows version - `g++ (rev2, Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.8.1` with `g++ main.cpp foo.cpp -o prog`, there could be a problem with your installation of g++ because i cannot recreate your error.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the return type of `goo()`. In C, the compiler assumes it's `int goo()`. In C++ (your case), the compiler assumes it's a call to `goo()`, not a function prototype.

Comment: That's C, C++ explicitly forbids declarations with no type. Either OPs compiler is old, he's disabled the error, or he's compiling specifying C as the language.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't put "void" in foo.h. Now i corrected it.